# Passing data from during post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 5 , and i have a problem with the partial views.

In the partial view,i put a form which works with a viewmodel named comment , and the main view works with another model which is photo.

The problem i encountered is that i can't pass the id of the photo from the main view to the partial view containing the comment model.

I tried this :

In the Main view :

```
@Html.Partial("CommentsPartial", new ViewDataDictionary() {{"id", @Model.PhotoID}})
```

In the partial view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "PhotoSharing", FormMethod.Post, ViewData["id"]))
```

but `ViewData["id"]` is always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "PhotoSharing", FormMethod.Post, ViewData["id"]))
```

should render something like:

```
<form action="PhotoSharing/AddComment" method="Post" id="1">
```

If you are familiar with html you should know that attributes on the form element are not passed back to the webserver.  Instead you should use either:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="@ViewData["id"]" />
```

or more Asp.Net MVC style:

```
@Html.Hidden("id", ViewData["id"])
```

On postback, you'll have to repopulate `ViewData` as it is not stateful:

```
public ActionResult AddComment(string id)
{
  ViewData["id"] = id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but may i ask you where to put the @Html.Hidden("id", ViewData["id"]) part please? in the main view or in the partial view ?

Comment: Inside the form (it's an input element).

Comment: I hope that't NOT the case :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to use this `RenderPartial(HtmlHelper, String, ViewDataDictionary)` [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470827%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Like this:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("PartialViewName", new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", Model.PhotoID } });
```

**Note** that this will override the default ViewData that all your other Views have by default. If you are adding anything to ViewData, it will not be in this new dictionary that you're passing to your partial view.

And access the above id as `ViewBag["id"]` anywhere in partial view.